# darken a hue - synonym

Tags: synonyms

When a person is bruised, the colour of the bruise changes from red to a darker shade of red and finally to black. We could call it as a darkening of hue but is there any other synonym of the same, which would imply the progression of a colour from a light shade to a darker shade (apart from darken) ?

e.g. sentence - As the intensity increased, so did the hue _________ .

Comment: _Darken_ is indeed the word; it's a causative/inchoative verb with the -_en_ affix of _lighten, redden, lengthen, broaden_, and it means 'become, or cause to become, dark' and generally indicates a slow gradual process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a bruise, or in clouds at dusk, or in an angry person's face, this process of darkening in color is called *[purpling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purple?q=purpling#purple__17)*.

When you make a color darker, artists and designers generally say that they *deepen* the hue.

So you can say:

> As the intensity increased, so did the hue *deepen*.

Comment: bruise was just an example, I want a general term to indicate the darkening. I,obviously, could not use purpling to describe the darkening of a leaf's green shade....

Answer (score 0):

Blacken, blackwash, turn black, color, discolor darkly, ink, shade deeply--that's all I can think of off the top of my head.